# Why the Jews didn't take the Egyptians' property in darkness plague

Tags: tanach

It is known that Jews took the vast majority of Egyptians' property was collected on the sea edge. Why didn't they take their property in dark plague? Why did they have to loan their property and did not take it under the cover of the darkness in the dark plague?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was in order to prove to the Egyptians their sense of integrity.

It says in [Shemos Rabbah 14:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.14.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וּבִשְׁלשֶׁת יְמֵי אֲפֵלָה...שֶׁהָיָה יִשְׂרָאֵל נִכְנַס לְתוֹךְ בָּתֵּיהֶן שֶׁל מִצְרִים וְהָיוּ רוֹאִין בָּהֶן כְּלֵי כֶסֶף וּכְלֵי זָהָב וּשְׂמָלוֹת, אִם הָיוּ אוֹמְרִים אֵין לָנוּ לְהַשְׁאִיל לָכֶם הָיוּ יִשְרָאֵל אוֹמְרִים לָהֶן הֲרֵי הוּא בְּמָקוֹם פְּלוֹנִי, בְּאוֹתָהּ שָׁעָה הָיוּ הַמִּצְרִיִּים אוֹמְרִים אִם הָיוּ אֵלּוּ רוֹצִים לְשַׁקֵּר בָּנוּ הָיוּ נוֹטְלִין אוֹתָן בִּימֵי הַחשֶׁךְ וְלֹא הָיִינוּ מַרְגִּישִׁין, שֶׁהֲרֵי רָאוּ אוֹתָן כְּבָר אַחַר שֶׁלֹא נָגְעוּ חוּץ מִדַּעְתֵּנוּ כְּמוֹ כֵן לֹא יַחֲזִיקוּ...
>
> *And in the three days of darkness...the Jews entered into the houses of the Egyptians and they saw in them vessels of silver, gold and garments. If they (the Egyptians) would say we didn't lend this to you, the Jews would say it is in this and this place. And at that time, the Egyptians would say (about the Jews)"If they wanted to lie / trick us, they could have taken them in the days of darkness and we wouldn't have felt it, because they saw them already. But they didn't touch them without our knowledge and so they didn't take them...*

Thus it proved a big kiddush Hashem as the Egyptians were forced to acknowledge the upstanding nature of the Jews who refused to take these things when they had the chance.